# Why would a function not run sometimes?

Tags: c++, function

Some Code:

```
Menu.Handle_MouseOvers(MousePosition); //Runs function below

void Handle_MouseOvers(Vector2<int> &MousePositions) ///Runs function below
{
    if (MenuButtons.size() > 0)
    MenuButtons[0].CheckContains(MousePositions);
}

void CheckContains(Vector2<int> &MousePositions)
{
    if (ButtonShape.GetShape() == "Rect" && ButtonShape.GetRect().Contains(MousePositions)) ///This doesn't run sometimes
    {
        MouseOver = true;
        std::cout << "MouseOver is true" << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "mouseOver is false" << std::endl;
        MouseOver = false;
    }
}
```

For some reason the ButtonShape.GetRect().Contains(MousePositions) only runs about 80% of the time. I have placed some couts inside the function, and when it fails, it does not run the function at all. I cannot figure out why it would work most of the time lol. Does anyone have any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

adding this as edit;

```
bool Contains(Vector2<int> &MousePosition)
{
    std::cout << MousePosition.x << " " << MousePosition.y << std::endl;
    if (MousePosition.x >= x && MousePosition.x <= x + Width && MousePosition.y >= y && MousePosition.y <= y + Height)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: short circuit evaluation?

Comment: Please post a complete example which recreates the issue you are asking about. The example should be as minimal as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason could be because this is a logical/boolean expression :

```
ButtonShape.GetShape() == "Rect" && ButtonShape.GetRect().Contains(MousePositions)
```

The `&&` works this way :

- If the expression on the left side is false, then it evaluates to false without evaluating the expression on the right side
- If the left expression evaluates to true, only then is the second expression evaluated

  - Now, if the right side expression evaluates to false, then the result is false
  - Otherwise, the final result is true.

---

If you are testing after removing `GetShape`, then ensure that `Shape` is being set to `Rect` every time.

---

If the function is still not running every time, then a possibility is that you might not be setting `MousePositions` correctly every time. This would, depending on your function code, appear as the function did not run.

Comment: Is the side on the left part of the boolean expression? Even though it... isn't? lol

Comment: @Chivos The left expression is part of the boolean expression, or are you asking something else ?

Comment: I took the first expression out, but still sometimes it just does not run the ButtonShape.GetRect().Contains(MousePositions);. I have a "hi" cout at the start of the contains functions and it does nothing.

Comment: @Chivos If I understand your program logic, isn't `GetRect` supposed to run only when `GetShape` is `Rect` ? So, are you always testing with the shape set to 'Rect' (even after removing `GetShape`)?

Comment: that is correct, and even with the check being taken out, it is still being set to a Rect

Comment: @Chivos Maybe `MousePositions` is not being passed every time or is being set incorrectly ? (Not much idea about vectors, I use `C` mainly)

Comment: I Got it! Thank you AshRj and everyone. I was not being very smart and did not have it Setting the shape correctly in an area! Pluses all around!

Answer (score 1):

If ButtonShape.GetShape() != "Rect", then the second expression (containing the call to ButtonShape.GetRect().Contains(MousePositions) ) will not get called, because it doesn't need to to satisfy the entire expression - this is called "short circuiting".

Comment: I took the ButtonShape.GetShape() out and it still happens.